# how to get two variables to print with one in decimal form

Tags: java, decimal

I am very new.  apologies in advance for my coding. I need to print a table that shows year and then a tab over, and then the value with a next line.  The value has to be in decimal form.
I have been reading and searching and mixing my code around.  I have found it for 1 variable but not for two in same line.  I have tried the printf, I have tried the good ol 100 / 100.0 and I either get errors or the decimal never goes to 2 places.  I do not need it rounded, just with 2 spaces after.  I am obviously going wrong somewhere.  I would appreciate any assistance.
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Investment1 {

public static double futureInvestmentValue(double investmentAmount, double monthlyInterestRate, int years){

double principal = 0.0;
double futureInvestmentValue = 0;
for (years = 1; years <=30; years++){
    //calculate futureInvestmentValue
    futureInvestmentValue = (investmentAmount * (Math.pow (1 + monthlyInterestRate, years * 12)));
    System.out.print(years + "\t" + futureInvestmentValue + "\n");

}//end for
    return futureInvestmentValue;
}//end futureInvestmentValue

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    //obtain Investment amount
    System.out.print("Enter Investment amount: ");
    double investmentAmount = input.nextDouble();

    //obtain monthly interest rate in percentage
    System.out.print("Enter annual interest rate in percentage: ");
    double annualInterestRate = input.nextDouble();
    double monthlyInterestRate = (annualInterestRate / 1200);

int years = 30;

System.out.println("Years\t" + "Future Value");
System.out.print(years + "\t");
System.out.print(years + "\t" + ((int)(futureInvestmentValue(investmentAmount, monthlyInterestRate, years))) + "\n");

}//end main
}//end Investment
```

Comment: What errors do you get? +1 for clear effort.

Comment: @ChrisCooney - with the above code (minus the extra print years line that I just took out.)  no errors, just not going to decimal place.  However, when I try to put sop"years + "\t" + "%.2f", future...  The error code is no suitable method found for print.  I then tried the string that was suggested below and the error codes went on and on.

Comment: @ChrisCooney, if I do the * 100 / 100.0 no error.  It just doesn't decimal to 2

Comment: What's the exact output with the 100/100.0 ?

Comment: @ChrisCooney it shows table just as needed - with years in one column and value as i.e.  1093.8068976709837

Comment: Okay. One solution that springs to mind is to get x = indexof the decimal place, and then substring 0 to x + 2?

Comment: @ChrisCooney perhaps I am putting the math in the wrong spot.  I put it under the double future value = (1 * 100)/100.0   If I put it in the print out area same way, its telling me that it is not a statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**system.out.format()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html):

```
System.out.format("%d \t %.2f", years, futureInvestmentValue);
```

Comment: Ah good :). I came up with `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");`

Answer (score 0):

you should read about format strings, heres a simple usage example:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%d %.2f",myint,myfloat));
```

`myint` will be printed as an integer (even if it's a floating point value) due to the use of the `%d` in the format string.
`myfloat` will be printed as a decimal number with 2 digits after the decimal point, thanks to the `%f.2` part in the format string.

Comment: I will definitely read more on that.  Question for you though.  how do you put the tab and next line into that?  would you do i,e. "%d\t %.2d\n"  ?

Comment: yep, only notice that you used %.2d instead of %.2f